# Create Discriminated Union Case from String

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to create DU cases from strings. The only way I can see doing this is by enumerating over the DU cases via `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases` and then picking the `UnionCase` that matches the string (by using `.Name`) and then making the actual DU case out of that by using `FSharpValue.MakeUnion`.

Isn't there an easier/more elegant way of doing this? In my scenario I have a DU with a couple of hundred cases for keywords. I have to read the strings (keywords) from a file and make the types out of them. I did some "optimization" by putting the cases into a Map but I was hoping there'd be a better way of doing this.

I have the following, for example:

```
type Keyword = 
    | FOO
    | BAR
    | BAZ
    | BLAH

let mkKeywords (file: string) =
    use sr = new StreamReader(file)

    let caseMap = 
        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<Keyword>)
        |> Array.map (fun c -> (c.Name, FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, [||]) :?> Keyword))
        |> Map.ofArray

    [
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            let l = sr.ReadLine().Trim()

            match caseMap.TryFind l with
            | Some c -> yield c
            | None -> failwith <| "Could not find keyword: " + l
    ]
```

Comment: How could it be any easier?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just starting out with F# and .Net, so I don't trust myself yet...:)

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets. Reflection is inherently less elegant.

Comment: Maybe a union is the wrong tool for the job. A few hundred cases signals poor use. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That could be the case. Here's what I'm trying to do: I have to use a bunch of (keyword, value) pairs as input to a foreign API. The API is given to me so there's not much I can do there. In my code I'm setting these (keyword, value) pairs all over the place so I chose a DU for representing the keywords to get type safety. On the other hand there are a bunch of (keyword, value) pairs that are default and are in a text file. This is what I have to read in. You can think of them as property files.

Comment: It won't give you type safety, but overloading the dynamic (`?`) operator would provide convenient syntax. You could store the key/values in a dictionary and define `let (?) (d: Dictionary<_,_>) key = d.[key]`. Usage would be: `keywords?FOO`.

Comment: Type providers are probably the only way you could achieve type safety for this (without code gen), but I doubt the effort would be worth it.

Comment: @Daniel A dictionary wrapped in a single case DU, with the dynamic operators defined on it, would appear type-safe and convenient.
Something along the lines of `type Dict<'A> = Dict of Dictionary<string,'A> with static member (?) (Dict d, key) = ...`

Answer (score 25):

I found [this](http://fssnip.net/9l) handy code snippet...

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let toString (x:'a) = 
    let (case, _ ) = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>)
    case.Name

let fromString<'a> (s:string) =
    match FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<'a> |> Array.filter (fun case -> case.Name = s) with
    |[|case|] -> Some(FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case,[||]) :?> 'a)
    |_ -> None
```

... which makes it easy to tack on two lines of code to any DU...

```
type A = X|Y|Z with
    override this.ToString() = FSharpUtils.toString this
    static member fromString s = FSharpUtils.fromString<A> s
```

Comment: The toString can be replaced by a deconstruction like:

let toString (x:'a) = 
  let (case, _ ) = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>)
  case.name

Comment: @Assassin Good suggestion. Changed.

Answer (score 10):

I would use pattern matching like this:

```
type Keyword = 
    | FOO
    | BAR
    | BAZ
    | BLAH


let matchKeyword (word:string) : Keyword option =
    match word with
    | "FOO"  -> Some FOO
    | "BAR"  -> Some BAR
    | "BAZ"  -> Some BAZ
    | "BLAH" -> Some BLAH
    | _      -> None
```

And maybe auto generate the match statement first time using regex in my editor, but only because you have hundreds of cases. But i am not sure if its a better solution then yours.

Comment: this can be improved with `nameof` operator introduced in F# 5.

Comment: How so? @paolo_

Comment: using, for instance `nameof FOO -> Some FOO` in the match statement instead of a string literal. Not a big improvement, but it avoids string literals.

Comment: @paolo_ is it case sensitive?

Answer (score 9):

As the cases have no value, another option is to use [enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216.aspx):

```
type Keyword = 
  | FOO   = 0
  | BAR   = 1
  | BAZ   = 2
  | BLAH  = 3

let strings = ["FOO";"BAR"]
let keywords = 
  [for s in strings -> s, Keyword.Parse(typeof<Keyword>, s)]
  |> Map.ofList
```

Then you can simply use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Phillip. I was thinking about using Enums but doesn't `.Parse` do the same as I'm doing under the hood?

Comment: Under the hood there is still a string lookup from the enum name to the value. `Enum.Parse` is just a little shorter.