# Unable to serialize Discriminated Union in F# Chiron

Tags: serialization, f#, discriminated-union

If I have:

```
type a = B | C
```

How do I write the static members ToJson and FromJson?

I know how to write it for a Record Type (which is shown in the examples at [Chiron: JSON + Ducks + Monads](https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-13-chiron-json-ducks-monads/index.html)  ) but I can't find any examples for a DU.

---

EDIT

Following s952163 helpful answer (and follow up comment), I have adapted the code to try and work with a 'simple' DU of choice A | B (rather than A of string | B of ...).  My code is now:

```
type SimpleDU =
    | A
    | B
    static member ToJson (t : SimpleDU) =
        match t with
        | A -> Json.writeNone "a"
        | B -> Json.writeNone "b"
    static member FromJson (_ : SimpleDU) =    
        json {
            let! duA = Json.tryRead "a"
            match duA with
            | Some s -> return s
            | None ->   return SimpleDU.B
        }
```

This compiles but when I try it with the sample operation code:

```
let a = A
let b = B
let a2json = a |> Json.serialize
let (json2a:SimpleDU) =  a2json |> Json.deserialize
let b2json = b |> Json.serialize 
let (json2b:SimpleDU) = b2json |> Json.deserialize
```

json2a is incorrectly returning SimpleDU.B

Comment: Speaking of general f# Yan Cui has posted an article about it.
Check it out: http://theburningmonk.com/2012/03/f-serializing-f-record-and-discriminated-union-types/

Comment: do you mean like you want to work with a Choice (like Choice1of2) type or just this simple DU? I can't test it right now but you could probably feed some dummy values after `Json.write "A"` like `"A"` bu  you would also probably want to `return s`. But it feels a bit clunky...

Comment: Can you take a look at https://github.com/xyncro/chiron/issues/26 and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @s952163 This is getting closer and thank you very much for your help but it is still not quite working.  I have edited the question again to show where I am now up to.

Comment: That means that the pattern match is failing to match on "a" and returns None. Try to match without B and probably you will get an error. This could be something with Chiron or maybe the let! syntax. Check what is in let! = duAI.. assume there is  a way to pattern match with a different syntax. Are you locked into Chiron btw?

Comment: @s952163 I am using Chiron as I can't use a reflection based library for my serialisation.  I tried printfn "%A" duA which shows: <null><null>.  Also: val a2json : Json = Object (map [("a", Null null)])

Comment: I believe CaringDev's answer below should do what you want with a nice and clean approach! If the follow-up article on DU types ever gets published please update the question with the link. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implementation which serializes `A` to `Object (map [("SimpleDU", String "a")])` instead of `Object (map [("a", Null null)])` is:

```
#I @"..\packages\Chiron.6.1.0\lib\net40"
#I @"..\packages\Aether.8.1.2\lib\net35"
#r "Chiron.dll"
#r "Aether.dll"

open Chiron

type SimpleDU = 
    | A
    | B

    static member ToJson x =
        Json.write "SimpleDU" <|
            match x with
            | A -> "a"
            | B -> "b"

    static member FromJson(_ : SimpleDU) = 
        json { 
            let! du = Json.tryRead "SimpleDU"
            match du with
            | Some "a" -> return A
            | Some "b" -> return B
            | Some x -> return! Json.error <| sprintf "%s is not a SimpleDU case" x
            | _ -> return! Json.error "Not a SimpleDU JSON"
        }

// val serializedA : Json = Object (map [("SimpleDU", String "a")])
let serializedA = A |> Json.serialize
let serializedB = B |> Json.serialize
let (a : SimpleDU) = serializedA |> Json.deserialize
let (b : SimpleDU) = serializedB |> Json.deserialize
let aMatches = a = A
let bMatches = b = B
let serializedABBAA = [ A; B; B; A; A ] |> Json.serialize
let (abbaa : SimpleDU list) = serializedABBAA |> Json.deserialize
let abbaaMatches = abbaa = [ A; B; B; A; A ]
// allFine = true
let allFine = aMatches && bMatches && abbaaMatches

let defects = 
    Array [ Object <| Map.ofList [ ("SimpleDU", String "c") ]
            Object <| Map.ofList [ ("Foo", String "bar") ] ]

// attempt = Choice2Of2 "Not a SimpleDU JSON"
let (attempt : Choice<SimpleDU list, string>) = defects |> Json.tryDeserialize
```

Instead of `"a"`and `"b"` you could use `true`and `false` which would get rid of the `Some x` case, but I'd rather have readable cases in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can add static members to DUs as well. In [Chiron Taming Types](https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-15-chiron-taming-types-in-the-wild/index.html) in the last paragraph there is a  link mentioning that some examples with DUs should be up soon. However assuming you can't wait and that you prefer Chiron over Json.NET or [FsPickler](http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/tutorial.html) here is an example. Probably there are some other ways but I'm not familiar with Chiron's operators so I decided to use a computation expression (pilfered from [Chiron Computation Expressions](https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2016/04-02-chiron-computation-expressions/index.html)). The idea is that you can pattern match. So probably you can pattern match over more complicated DUs as well. If you are familiar with Chiron I'm sure it can be made more idiomatic. You can see that Chiron itself is using DUs, and for example the Json object is map.

```
#I @"..\packages\Chiron.6.1.0\lib\net40"
#I @"..\packages\Aether.8.0.2\lib\net35"
#I @"..\packages\FParsec.1.0.1\lib\net40-client"
#r "Chiron.dll"
#r "Aether.dll"
#r "Fparsec.dll"

open Aether
open Chiron
open Chiron.Operators
open FParsec

type SimpleDU =
    |A of string
    |B of int * bool
    static member ToJson (x: SimpleDU) =
        match x with
        | A s -> Json.write "A" s
        | B (i, b) -> Json.write "B" (i, b)
    static member FromJson (_ : SimpleDU) =    
      json {
        let! duA = Json.tryRead "A"
        match duA with
        | Some s -> return A s
        | None ->
          let! x = Json.read "B"
          return B x
      }
```

And here's how it works:

```
let a = A "Jason"
let b = B (13,true)
let a2json = a |> Json.serialize //val Json = Object (map [("A", String "Jason")])
let (json2a:SimpleDU) =  a2json |> Json.deserialize //val json2a : SimpleDU = A "Jason"
let b2json = b |> Json.serialize 
let (json2b:SimpleDU) = b2json |> Json.deserialize
```

There are some examples in the source code as well that might be useful for you:[Chiron](https://github.com/xyncro/chiron/tree/master/tests/Chiron.Tests)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828630/2314532 might help you. That answer points to [this F# snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/9l) defining `ToString` and `FromString` functions for discriminated unions:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let toString (x:'a) = 
    match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>) with
    | case, _ -> case.Name

let fromString<'a> (s:string) =
    match FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<'a> |> Array.filter (fun case -> case.Name = s) with
    |[|case|] -> Some(FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case,[||]) :?> 'a)
    |_ -> None
```

You would still need to get from the string (just "A" or "B") to the full DU object (e.g., reading the rest of the DU's data in s952163's `SimpleDU` example), and as I haven't used Chiron yet, I can't help you much there. But that may give you a starting point.