# Enums in F# for strings

Tags: enums, f#

I'm working on a legacy database with no systems to which I can modify. Because of type providers I decided to use F#. It's not so simple now that I'm into it. How do I structure a field in my DB that has only the following strings? It's sort of like an ENUM. I've tried the following but haven't quite gotten it.

**Attempt 1**

```
type SuspendedDriver = "SI"
type ActiveDriver = "IMPRESO"
type Applicant = "NO"
type TemporaryDriver = "TEMP"
type Uncertain = "NULL"

type DriverStatus =
    | SuspendedDriver
    | ActiveDriver
    | Applicant
    | TemporaryDriver
    | Uncertain

type Driver = {
    status : DriverStatus
    }
```

*Error*

```
Error FS0618: Invalid literal in type (FS0618) (ScriptTest)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
type DriverStatus =
    | SuspendedDriver = "SI"
    | ActiveDriver = "IMPRESO"
    | Applicant = "NO"
    | TemporaryDriver = "TEMP"
    | Uncertain = "NULL"
```

*Error*

```
Error FS0951: Literal enumerations must have type int, uint, int16,
uint16, int64, uint64, byte, sbyte or char (FS0951) (ScriptTest)
```

Comment: You can’t assign strings to union cases; you’ll need to write a function to convert the union to/from a string. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21559837/47636

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you cannot define an enum that has values erased to strings. Enums can only be integers (of various types).

#### Using enums in an ugly way

You *could* use the actual names of the enum fields and then parse them using `Enum.Parse`, but that's probably not  good idea, because the enum cases would be fairly obscure codes. But just for the record, the following works:

```
type DriverStatus =
   | SI = 0

System.Enum.Parse(typeof<DriverStatus>, "SI") :?> DriverStatus
```

#### Cleaner parsing into discriminated union

In practice, I would do what Sam recommends and write a function to parse the string from the database. This has the advantage that you'll need to figure out what to do with errors in the database (the value can always be something wrong):

```
type DriverStatus =
   | SuspendedDriver
   | ActiveDriver

let parseDriverStatus = function
   | "SI" -> SuspendedDriver
   | "IMPRESO" -> ActiveDriver 
   | code -> failwith (sprintf "Wrong driver code! %s" code)
```

#### Using the cool Enum SQL provider

Finally, if you happen to be using MS SQL database, then the [SQL Command Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/sqlenumprovider.quickstart.html) project has a neat feature that lets you automatically import enum-like types from SQL database itself, which might actually be exactly what you need in this case.

Comment: WOW! Thank you Tomas :) Getting super into F#. I already want to mess with the type provider (or just the types) and get more discriminated unions. Any resources that provide this? I'm thinking an F# guide for working with legacy databases or structures would be great. Is there one out there?