# The non-generic type Type does not expect type arguments

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am creating a simple test type provider.

I want to provide a string, and return a type with the type name equal to that provided string.

But the result doesn't work, saying that BasicProvider is a non-generic type.

**Error:**

> The non-generic type 'SimpleStringProvider.BasicProvider' does not
>   expect any type arguments, but here is given 1 type argument(s)

```
module SimpleStringProvider

open ProviderImplementation
open ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open System.Reflection

[<TypeProvider>]
type BasicProvider (config : TypeProviderConfig) as this =
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces (config)

    let ns = "SimpleStringProvider.StringProvider"
    let asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    let staticParams = [ProvidedStaticParameter("value", typeof<string>)]

    let createTypes () =

        let myType = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "StringProvider", Some typeof<obj>)
        // let myProp = ProvidedProperty("MyProperty", typeof<string>, isStatic = true, getterCode = (fun args -> <@@ "Hello world" @@>))
        // myType.AddMember(myProp)
        let instantiationFunction _ paramValues =
                let typeName = (paramValues |> Array.head).ToString()
                ProvidedTypeDefinition(
                        asm,
                        ns,
                        typeName,
                        Some typeof<obj>
                    )

        do myType.DefineStaticParameters(
            parameters = staticParams,
            instantiationFunction = instantiationFunction
            )
        do this.AddNamespace(ns, [myType])

[<assembly:TypeProviderAssembly>]
do ()
```

Here is how I test it in a script:

```
#r @".\src\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SimpleStringProvider.dll"


open SimpleStringProvider

type X = SimpleStringProvider.BasicProvider<"test">
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but createTypes() is never called, is it?

In the example in the sdk, it's called on contruction. See [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK#the-providedtypes-api---a-basic-type-provider) for instance.

Comment: yes, that solves my issues. thanks